# Is it possible to embed windows photo viewer into C# form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to be able to have something like a picturebox but with the ability to zoom in/out, etc.

I tried some things from the internet. But unfortunately the image is blurry when you zoom in, but with windows photo viewer it's not. So I simply want to embed it into my C# application somehow, is it possible?